# Beginner-level virtual library program troubles, how do I let the user create an array or 'def'?

Tags: python, arrays, function

Alright, so I'm bad with words so I painted you all a beautiful picture hoping that whole picture is worth a thousand words thing is true:

[image]

However, if the picture didn't do the job I'll try to describe my issue. I'm trying to make a sort of beginner level virtual library in Python. However, first here is my code thus-far:

```
book_title = []
book_page_count = []
book_publish_date = []
book_author = []

def elsePhrase():
    print("Wrong input, I'll just send you back to the menu.\n")
    menu()

def menu():
    print("- - - - - - - -- PROGRAM  MENU -- - - - - - - -")
    print("Welcome Book Sorter, what would you like to do? \n")
    print("1 ) Add a book")
    print("2 ) List a specific book's details")
    print("3 ) List all recorded complete book details")
    menu_Choice = input("4 ) Exit.\n\n")

    if menu_Choice == 1:
          add_book()
    elif menu_Choice == 2:
          list_book()
    elif menu_Choice == 3:
          list_all()
    elif menu_Choice == 4:
          exit()
    else:
        print("Error: Please enter a number as shown and try again.")
        print("-----------------------------------------------------------\n\n")
        menu()

def add_book():
    print("\nYou selected: Add book. Please fill out the following information: \n")
    title = raw_input("Book title: ")
    book_title.append(str(title))
    page_count = raw_input("Book page count: ")
    book_page_count.append(page_count)
    publish_date = raw_input("Book publish date: ")
    book_publish_date.append(publish_date)
    author = raw_input("Book author: ")
    book_author.append(author)
    print("\nProcess complete.")
    Restart()

def list_book():
    # Find out how to fix this
    print("You selected: list book. Please select a book from below: ")
    print(book_title)
    choice = raw_input("\n")

def list_all():
    #Find out how to make this actually look not-shitty and make sense.
    print(book_title)
    print(book_page_count)
    print(book_publish_date)
    print(book_author)

def Restart():
    toMenu = raw_input("\n\tWould you like to go back to the main menu? Y / N\t\n\n")
    if toMenu == "Y":
        menu()
    elif toMenu == "N":
        toExit = raw_input("Oh.. Okay then want me to just exit the program? Y /N\n\n")
        if toExit == "Y":
            exit()
        elif toExit == "N":
            print("Alright, I guess I'll just leave you be, you know where the big red X button is I guess. Take your time.")
        else:
            elsePhrase()
    else:
        elsePhrase()

def main():
    menu()

main()
```

Yeah, it's bad I know, I'm sorry; I am still trying to learn.

Anyway, where I am having trouble is I want to basically create a unique array or 'def' that has all this information in it.. So say for example I want to add a book into this library it will make a block of information that holds the title, author, page count, publish date, etc.. All together in a comfortable little box of information I can call later. The issue is I have no idea how to actually do this with an undetermined amount of information defined by the user.

So.. That about sums it up I guess, thanks very much in advance for any help!

**TL;DR: I don't understand how to let the user enter a block of seperate information (Title, author, page count, etc..), bind it all together, and then print it out again on demand easily(Saying "Find details on X and Y" where X is book 1 / all the information entered in step 1 and Y is all the information on book 2 in a different step 1. All done multiple-infinite times.**

I hope this made sense, please free to ask me anything, I just would really like to be able to do this, thanks!

Comment: There's a Python data structure missing from your program: I think you might be interested in [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  (`namedtuple`s would work too, but might as well start with `dict`s.)

Comment: So how would I go about letting a user create a dictionary though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that should get you well on your way:

```
import sys

# Python 2/3 compatibility shim
if sys.hexversion >= 0x3000000:
    inp = input
    rng = range
else:
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

class Book:
    @classmethod
    def from_prompt(cls):
        title  = inp('Enter title: ').strip()
        author = inp('Enter author: ').strip()
        pages  = get_int('Page count: ')
        date   = inp('Publication date: ').strip()
        return cls(title, author, pages, date)

    def __init__(self, title, author, pages, date):
        self.title  = title
        self.author = author
        self.pages  = pages
        self.date   = date

    def __str__(self):
        return "Book: {title}\nAuthor: {author}\nPage count: {pages}\nPublish Date: {date}".format(
            title=self.title, author=self.author, pages=self.pages, date=self.date
        )

class Library:
    def __init__(self, books=None):
        self.books = []
        self.title_index = {}
        if books:
            for book in books:
                self.add(book)

    def add(self, book):
        self.books.append(book)
        self.title_index[book.title] = book

    def find_title(self, title):
        return self.title_index.get(title, None)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n\n'.join(str(book) for book in self.books)

def main():
    #
    # You get to write this part,
    # but here are some code examples:
    #
    lib = Library()

    book1 = Book('Fun with Dick and Jane', 'May Hill Arbuthnot', 160, '1951')
    lib.add(book1)

    book2 = Book('The Adventures of Pinocchio', 'Carlo Collodi', 171, '1911')
    lib.add(book2)

    # prompt for book 3 information
    book3 = Book.from_prompt()
    lib.add(book3)

    # find a book and display its information
    print('='*30)
    print(lib.find_title('The Adventures of Pinocchio'))

    # display the whole library contents
    print('='*30)
    print(lib)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```